# How to show $\mathbb R^n/\mathbb Z^n$ is diffeomorphic to torus $\mathbb T^n$?

Tags: manifolds, group-actions

Suppose the additive group $\mathbb Z^n$ acts on $\mathbb R^n$ through translation. How to show $\mathbb R^n/\mathbb Z^n$ is diffeomorphic to torus $\mathbb T^n$? The translation action is given by $$\psi_g:\mathbb R^n\rightarrow \mathbb R^n,\ x\mapsto g+x.$$

Comment: What is your definition for $\mathbb{T}^n$?

Comment: $\mathbb T^n=\mathbb S^1\times \ldots\mathbb S^1$ ($n$-times).. But you can use anything that works..

Comment: @PtF: Do you know the **circle group** $T$? Do you know that $T=\{z\in\mathbb C\mid|z|=1\}\cong\mathbb R/\mathbb Z$? Are these useful for you?

Comment: Did you tried $F(x_1,...,x_n)=(e^{2\pi ix_1},...,e^{2\pi i x_n})$?

Comment: @BabakS. I didn't know that group but it might be useful..Thanks

Comment: @Tomás I was thinking about using it but I gave up for I tought I wouldn't be able to prove surjectivity.. But I'll try..

Comment: @PtF: Think about it so if it is not useful, I'll remove it.

Comment: @PtF: If $y=\text{e}^{\theta i}\in T$ so by $x=\frac{\theta}{2\pi}\in\mathbb R$ and $f(x)=y$.

Comment: Ok, if I write the whole proof formally I'll post here.Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

Hint: From group theory point of view, the *circle group* denoted by $T$ and defined as $$\{z\in\mathbb C\mid|z|=1\}=\{\text{e}^{i\theta}\mid\theta\in\mathbb R\}$$  We can define a homomorphism $f$ as follows: $$f:\mathbb R\to T,~~~f(x)=\text{e}^{2\pi x i}$$ Show that $f$ is a surjection with kernel $\mathbb Z$.

Comment: Ok I'll try.. Thanks

Comment: Hey @Babak, if I show $\ker(f)=\mathbb Z$ then it won't be injective, right?

Comment: @PtF: Yes! but according to thr first theorem of homomorphism $R/Z$ and $C$ are the same.

Answer (score 1):

Another perspective: $\mathbb{R}^n/\mathbb{Z}^n$ is a connected, compact, abelian Lie group of dimension $n$. How many of those do you know of?

Comment: None of them =(

Comment: I apologize. The fact that you asked for diffeomorphic and people were discussing groups led me to believe you were privvy to Lie groups! There is only one abelian connected compact Lie group of dimension $n$--the $n$-torus.

Comment: Ok, I guess the application $\phi:\mathbb R^n/\mathbb Z^n\rightarrow \mathbb T^n$ given by $\phi([x])=(e^{2\pi ix_1}, \ldots, e^{2\pi ix_n})$ will work out, what you think?

Comment: But will that be a bijection @Alex Youcis?

Comment: @PtF Yeah, that's the idea.