# How to show $\mathbb{R}^n/\mathbb{Z}^n$ is diffeomorphic to torus $T^n$?

Tags: differential-geometry

My question is related to this one [How to show $\mathbb R^n/\mathbb Z^n$ is diffeomorphic to torus $\mathbb T^n$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/340536/how-to-show-mathbb-rn-mathbb-zn-is-diffeomorphic-to-torus-mathbb-tn)

I understand everything up to showing that the map $F:\mathbb{R}^n/\mathbb{Z}^n\rightarrow T^n$ is a bijection but how do we prove $F$ and $F^{-1}$ are differentiable?

Comment: Just like in the base case $\Bbb R/\Bbb Z\to S^1$.

Comment: Ok but how do we do for base case?

Comment: Maybe this is a useful hint: For a small enough open set, what does the projection map look like?